# What is the UK-English equivalent of "Public Works"?

Tags: british-english

Morning,

I am translating someone's CV and they have experience managing finances for the state government, including regarding what wordreference translates to 'Public Works' - Construction works and other projects realized by the state.

I have to be honest, the term sounds weird to me, and google searches bring up results from Canada, US, and New Zealand, but not the UK. Unfortunately, I now live abroad in and can't for the life of me think of the term that we actually use. Can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: "Public works" is fine, or at least, understandable. I suppose you could say "**Public-sector** projects" or some such.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Just to clarify for OP: "public works" (roads, bridges, water, other infrastructure) is a subset of "public sector" (which would include judicial, military,   census, tax collection, other things that don't require the pouring of concrete).

Answer (score 5):

The term "**Public Works**" to denote the construction of public buildings and infrastructure may seem un-British because the **Ministry of Public Building and Works** was absorbed into other ministries and agencies in 1970. (And its predecessors the Ministry of Works and the Office of Works were mainly concerned with royal properties and military and government buildings.)

However, the term "**Public Works**" is still in use in official documents and on UK government websites, e.g.:

- "Machinery for public works, building or the like" from
  [www.gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/trade-tariff/commodities/8479100000)
- "Public Works Loan Board" from [www.dmo.gov.uk](http://www.dmo.gov.uk/index.aspx?page=PWLB/Introduction)

Other British sources will often use the phrase "**public works sector**", e.g.:

- "Case study of the public works sector in the UK and Greece", a [dissertation](https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/pprg/documentsarchive/phdtheses/despina_pachnou_thesis.pdf) for the University of Nottingham.
- "Underestimating costs in public works projects: error or lie?", an
  [essay](http://www.ivoryresearch.com/writers/rachel-parker/) by a British researcher.